# Get only object key values which have non blank using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array which has specific keys of an object `obj`

```
arr_keys = ['key1','key4','key5'];
```

And I also have an object with key value pair as below

```
obj = { 'key1' : '', 'key2' : 'val2', 'key3' : '', 'key4' : 'val4', 'key5' : '' };
```

Now I am looking for some function in lodash which could give me `x` object filtered from `obj` object as

```
 x = _.someFunc(obj,arr_keys)

// x = { 'key4' : 'val4'  }
```

We can see that I have only got key value pair of `'key4' : 'val4'` and ommited 
keys `'key1'` and `'key5'` as they had blank values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could chain `pickBy` and `identity` to get properties where value is not empty string or undefined and then use `pick` method to get only properties where key is in array.

```js
const arr = ['key1','key4','key5'];
const obj = { 'key1' : '', 'key2' : 'val2', 'key3' : '', 'key4' : 'val4', 'key5' : '' };
const result = _(obj).pickBy(_.identity).pick(arr).value()
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's very easy just try this fn

```js
  let arr_keys = ['key1', 'key4', 'key5'];
 let obj = { 'key1': '', 'key2': 'val2', 'key3': '', 'key4': 'val4', 'key5': '' };
 function someFunc(obj, arr_keys) {
    let resultObj = {};
    arr_keys.forEach((element) => {
      if (obj[element])
        resultObj[element] = obj[element];
    })
    return resultObj;
  }
  console.log(someFunc(obj,arr_keys))
```

so the result will be { 'key4' : 'val4'  }

Answer (score 1):

Use lodash's `_.pickBy()` to get an object from another object using a list of keys and another condition (v not blank):

```js
const arr_keys = ['key1','key4','key5'];

const obj = { 'key1' : '', 'key2' : 'val2', 'key3' : '', 'key4' : 'val4', 'key5' : '' };

const result = _.pickBy(obj, (v, k) => v && arr_keys.includes(k));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

With vanilla JS you can convert to pairs using `Object.entries()`, filter the array of pairs, and then use `Object.entries()` to convert back to an object:

```js
const arr_keys = ['key1','key4','key5'];

const obj = { 'key1' : '', 'key2' : 'val2', 'key3' : '', 'key4' : 'val4', 'key5' : '' };

const result = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(obj)
    .filter(([k, v]) => v && arr_keys.includes(k))
);


console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```